# connect C main.exe with powershell

Tags: c, powershell

I'm creating a C program to join several powershell scripts to facilitate their execution.

But before I run the scripts I need to connect with powersheel.

I need to run these commands:

```
$Session, $Credentials = C:\PowerShell\connect.ps1 | 
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Credentials |
Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking |
Set-ADServerSettings -ViewEntireForest $true
```

I tried to run the powershell command at the beginning of my C program but it opens a new powershell: system("powershell");

How can I connect my main.exe to powershell and then run the commands?

Comment: Powershell already is a programming language. Is there a particular reason why you would want to create a C wrapper when you can just join the functionalities of your scripts into a single script?

Answer (score 0):

Dear try de following simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
   system("start powershell.exe mkdir c://test_2");
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: why mkdir??? @Daniel Sagarra